# Where can I find a complete world provinces polygons dataset?

Tags: flutter, mobile, geofencing, region

I am looking to make a mobile app (in flutter) that can deduce in which province / region / county the device is located based on geolocation. For example, if the device's geolocation is 'X' I want to be able to translate that to "Orange county, California".

Where can I find such datasets, for each country - polygon coords of its' regions including region name (ie. {...'United States': {...'California: {'Orange County' : [coords coords coords...], 'San Diego': [coords coords coords...]...}}}).

Logics-wise I thought about using some sort of ray casting algorithm, if you have any good references in that regard (geofencing) it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Will this help? https://medium.com/flutter-community/get-a-users-location-in-flutter-20f488ac8043

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/geopoint_location 
You can download and run example directly https://github.com/synw/geopoint_location 
You can see example show address of current location

working demo of example code

[image]

code snippet

```
class PositionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PositionWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.locationPoint,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final GeoPoint locationPoint;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Latitude ${locationPoint.latitude}"),
        Text("Longitude ${locationPoint.longitude}"),
        Text("Altitude ${locationPoint.altitude}"),
        Text("Speed ${locationPoint.speed}"),
        Text("Address ${locationPoint.address}"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great! I couldn't find the method by which this package does the translation though, where can I find the region names and modify them  / define new regions etc? it seems to give weird region names and sublocalities sometimes (ie. "central development region" etc..), I would like to review all the predefined names and perhaps edit a few, is that part of the package or hardcoded on the device's OS?

Comment: also, some points yield null region+locality+sublocality, trying to understand how this package works 'under the hood'

Comment: I would suggest post issue to let github owner know your question.